# Why does column_name = (select column_name) work and not column_name=null

Tags: mysql

I am fetching some rows for my model but the view has so many criteria i was getting tired of writing many models.To make work easier i don't want to write new select statements for every criteria selected so at first i tried to try and still return something from the select even when one of more of the available criteria are/is not supplied by the user.

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = null AND member_club_id = 1 AND membership_year = null;
```

and returns nothing

Finally i tried

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = (select member_id) AND member_club_id = (select member_club_id=1) AND membership_year = (select membership_year);
```

and this works correctly.

I am still new to mysql and i wanted to know why this second approach worked.

Of interest is `select member_club_id=1` and `member_id = (select member_id)` for instance.

In `member_id = (select member_id)` i was thinking this would be read as `member_id=member_id` since i had no variable called `member id` and therefore fail.

In `select member_club_id=1` i thought i would get `unknown column` error in `member_club_id` and therefore fail.

Someone help out.

Comment: That should be `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in first query you maybe want do this

```
 SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id is null 
                         AND member_club_id = 1 
                         AND membership_year is null;
```

- there is not in mysql `= null` but `is null`

in your second query i dont think this `member_id = (select member_id)` will do something

its like you saying `WHERE member_id = member_id`  this automatically return true in all cases. Thats why you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `=` with `NULL`. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html